# Have two exchange servers to communicate together

Tags: exchange-2007, email-server, exchange-2010, domain-controller

We have Exchange Server 2007 using our domain `ddd.com`.

We created an isolated network with a firewall/gateway and installed a DC and Exchange Server 2010 using a demo/test domain (`ddd.loc`).

We opened all the needed ports in the firewall (`10.10.2.88`) to the Exchange Server 2010.

In our main Domain Controller (10.10.2.3) we defined the domain `ddd.loc` with IP `10.10.2.88` (firewalls). We also we defined MX records to the same IP (`10.10.2.88`)

We did that so when we send email from my email `me@ddd.com` it will go to the Exchange Server 2010.

Anyways, all the pings test from to any servers are OK.

But we are not able to send or receive emails. Between these Exchange Servers
we can not send any email from the 2010 to any email in general (emails are pending).

Also, in Exchange 2007 we are getting error `#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##`

[image]

Comment: no idea what your question is

Comment: `but when we test we get error` - care to share?

Comment: Sometimes, when we know what test you actually did and what errors you actually got, we can help you fix the problem straight away. Without that, it could be anything from a firewall problem to low flying alien spacecraft interfering with your wiring.

Comment: we have 2 exchange server we want them to send emails to each other based on the email domain, id I send email with my outlook to test@dddddddd.loc it will send it directly to the other exchange server (IP) and the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Dont completely understand the whole question but.

Sending an email to the 2010 exchange will entail you creating DNS pointer in you production DNS Server (e.g. your Domain Controller)

> how to make it so that the 2010 will send email directly to the 2007

think you want to send email from the dddd.local through the 2007 server this will envolve routing the SMTP to 10.10.2.11 << [Link explaining the process](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/planning-architecture/smtp-routing-exchange-2010-part3.html)

You will though need to make sure your firewall is configured correctly

If you could phase the question better ill do my best to answer if the answers are not what you expected

Comment: Are there DNS pointers in your DC's pointing to the other domains? - E.G. ddd.local on ddd.com's dns server point to 10.0.0.1?

Comment: it points to (10.10.2.88) and the dns port is open to 10.0.0.1

Comment: also the MX records point to (10.10.2.88) and the SMTP port is open to 10.0.0.11

Comment: Are you using it as NAT? because unless you are using NAT and forwarding the ports to the correct machine it will fail...  if you are not using NAT try pinging 10.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.11 from the live network e.g. 10.10.2.3

Comment: i'm using NAT, but shouldn't it work if we open the right ports?

Comment: If you open the ports but they are not being pointed then they are useless make sure that on the NAT configuration that all ports for mail are going to 10.0.0.11

Comment: yes I did that port-forward